# how to separate multiple regex matches in the same line

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to use regex to parse values written in a `(key###value)` format. The value will always be a number. Anyway, I figure it will be simplest to do it with python, so here's some code I'm trying:

```
import re

line = "(text 1###123)(text 2###345)";

matchObj = re.match( r'\(.*###[0-9]+\)', line)

if matchObj:
   print matchObj.group(0) # produces (text 1###123)(text 2###345)
   # print matchObj.group(1) # gives an error
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

Even though there are two distinct objects matching the regex that I wrote, python returned them to me as a single string -- not what I wanted. How can I fix this?

In fact, what I really want is to separate the string into something like `["text 1", "123", "text 2", "345]`. So if anyone has a simple way to accomplish that, I'd greatly appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have the right regex for this, you need to have capture groups. Your example has the parens escaped. Here's what you actually need as the regular expression. The `?` after the `*` makes it non-greedy (so that it tries to take as few characters as possible while still matching).

```
\((.*?)###([0-9]+)\)
```

Your current regular expression only has escaped parens, so you don't actually have any capture groups.  To get all the matches, you'd need to use `re.findall`. But if you need to use two capture groups, this will produce something like this:

```
regex = r'\((.*?)###([0-9]+)\)'
re.findall(regex, "(text 1###123)(text 2###345)") # [("text 1", "123"), ("text 2", "345")]
```

If you want to flatten it, that's quite simple to do as well.

Comment: Non-greedy `(.*?)` is necessary here, otherwise that `findall` returns  `[('text 1###123)(text 2', '345')]`

Comment: @JanneKarila good point. I think I had it initially as `[^#]*` and then decided that would make too many assumptions, so went back to `.*` without thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

A few points are coming into play in this question.

1. First is what percisely `re.match()` does. This function actually expects to be able to start a match **at the beginning** of the string, which in this case it cannot as you have an opening parenthesis there. So you will instead want to look at the `re.search()`, and more likely, the `re.findall()` functions.
2. Also, you do not need to escape groups in Python as you do in other languages.
3. You probably do not want to use `.*` as this tends to be greedy. While you can get away with `.*?`, it is often better to take the time to give regex a more specific search.

In summary, I recommend the following:

```
matchObj = re.findall(r'(([\w\d ]+)###(\d+))', line)
```

This will result in an easy to sort through array:

```
>>> matchObj
[('text 1###123', 'text 1', '123'), ('text 2###345', 'text 2', '345')]
>>> matchObj[0]
('text 1###123', 'text 1', '123')
```

Comment: Minor goof: the `\(` is to match the opening paren, so `re.match()` should work with the exception that it returns only one result. If you add escapes to my first and last parens, then your results might be even better: `[('text 1', '123'), ('text 2', '345')]`